# Сохраняет одну картинку из из множества картинок

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Сделал парсер, который должен скачивать картинки ко мне в папку: "Картинки". Но почему то он сохраняет последний элемент вместо множества картинок. Что делать подскажите?

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_image(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    image = []
    for item in items:
        image.append(
            item.find('img', class_='lozad').get('data-src')
            )
    return  image

def safe_image(image):
    for name in image:
        name = name.split('/')[-1]
    for i in image:
        with open('Картинки/' + name, 'wb') as file:
            for chunk in requests.get(i):
                file.write(chunk)

def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        image = get_image(html.content)
        safe_image(image)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема находится в методе `safe_image`. Цикл по созданию имен работает в холостую. Эти имена пропадают со следующей итерацией и нигде не сохраняются. Поэтому все картинки пишутся в файл с одним и тем же именем, перезаписывая предыдущий. В итоге оставляя последний со страницы.

Достаточно одного цикла

```
def safe_image(image):
    for i in image:
        name = i.split('/')[-1]
        with open('Картинки/' + name, 'wb') as file:
            for chunk in requests.get(i):
                file.write(chunk)
```